# Symfony2 Create And Download CSV

Tags: php, symfony, csv

I am trying to create a csv and download it to the browser. There is almost ZERO documentation on this in Symfony2 from what I can find.

Here is my code:

```
 // Pass in all of the variables that will make up the pdf...
    $response = $this->renderView('WICPurchaseOrderBundle:PurchaseOrder:csv.html.twig', array( "data"=>$data
        )
    );
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/csv'); // This is line 929 in the error.
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="teams.csv"');

    return $response;
```

This is the error I get:

```
 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/symfonydev/src/WIC/PurchaseOrderBundle/Controller/PurchaseOrderController.php line 929
```

Anyone have an experience with CSV's in Symfony2 and can help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a successful CSV download in my Symfony2 application, and it looks like you are close to getting it right. Change this line:

```
$response = $this->renderView('WICPurchaseOrderBundle:PurchaseOrder:csv.html.twig', 
    array( "data"=>$data)
);
```

to this:

```
$response = $this->render('WICPurchaseOrderBundle:PurchaseOrder:csv.html.twig', 
    array( "data"=>$data)
);
```

the `renderView()` method renders a template and returns its content, but does not create a response.  the `render()` method returns a `Response` object containing the content from the template:

See the docs about [Rendering a template](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#rendering-templates)

Comment: wow, I cant believe it was that simple. Thanks so much for your help!